# VB.Net to optimize execution by keeping data other than fetching data from database everytime

Tags: vb.net, optimization, enums, structure

I am newbie in vb.net I am trying to optimize my code execution that i am working on . i am working on a program having more than 45 forms. In every form its calling the function IsPowerUser to check is power user

If  we can store all details about user while logging in  , then  we need to use these values every time when we needed instead of collecting data from database . May be this question belongs to VB Basics.

Comment: Using .NET 4 or above? It matters for the answer I'm about to post.

Comment: i am working with framework version 3.5

Comment: Post the relevant code from `ModPublicfunctioons` please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lazy initialization to postpone the database call until you actually need the information (if ever), and then store the value for re-use.

```
Private _isPowerUser As New Lazy(Of Boolean)(AddressOf GetIsPowerUser)

Public Function IsPowerUser() As Boolean
    Return _isPowerUser.Value
End Function

Private Function GetIsPowerUser() As Boolean
    ' Retrieve the information from the database and return
    Return True Or False
End Function
```

In this sample, `_isPowerUser` is a backing field that uses lazy initialization. It is first initialized when someone calls `IsPowerUser`. Under the covers, `Lazy(Of T)` then calls the delegate `GetIsPowerUser()` that does all the heavy lifting to retrieve the value from the database.

`Lazy(Of T)` only needs to call `GetIsPowerUser()` once.
In other words: any consecutive calls to `IsPowerUser()` do not trigger `GetIsPowerUser()`.

**EDIT** (1/2)

`Lazy(Of T)` was not introduced until .NET 4, so here is a code sample that works for .NET 2 and above:

```
Private _isPowerUser As Boolean?
Private lazyLock As New Object

Public Function IsPowerUser() As Boolean
    If Not _isPowerUser.HasValue Then
        SyncLock lazyLock
            If Not _isPowerUser.HasValue Then
                _isPowerUser = GetIsPowerUser()
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End If
    Return _isPowerUser.Value
End Function

Private Function GetIsPowerUser() As Boolean
    ' Retrieve the information from the database and return
    Return True Or False
End Function
```

**EDIT** (2/2)

I changed my code sample to work in a multi-user environment:

```
Private _powerUsers As New Dictionary(Of Long, Boolean)
Private ReadOnly LazyLock As New Object


Public Function IsPowerUser(userId As Long) As Boolean
    If Not _powerUsers.ContainsKey(userId) Then
        SyncLock LazyLock
            If Not _powerUsers.ContainsKey(userId) Then
                _powerUsers.Add(userId, GetIsPowerUser(userId))
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End If
    Return _powerUsers.Item(userId)
End Function

Private Function GetIsPowerUser(UId As Long) As Boolean
    ' Retrieve the information from the database and return
    Return True Or False
End Function
```

Usage example:

```
    Dim Steven As Long = 454151
    If IsPowerUser(Steven) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Steven is a power user.")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Steven is a normal user.")
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much Steven Liekens for your reply. I am Newbie in VB development. Let me work with your code.

Comment: @Renjith.R You can't use the `Lazy` type in 3.5, so I added a new code sample.

Comment: Oh thank you so much.... i was about to change the version of .net framework. I was surfing to get more detail about .net version updation. I am asking is there any problem if i am updating my .net version to 4.5 (newer version)

Comment: That's nearly impossible to predict, but you can get a good idea of what you need to change by reading these articles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171868(v=vs.100).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry, i am confused with your code.. There is 'ModPublicfunctioons.vb' named module and ispoweruser function defined in this module. This function retrieves data from database every occasion when we calls the ispoweruser(). When the user logging in i like to call a function and sets all data in a data structure or in an array and i like to retrieve the saved values during further execution. Please specify what to place in module and what to place in form .

Comment: I added another code sample that supports multiple users. All you have to do is move your existing code from `ispoweruser` to `GetIsPowerUser()`.

Comment: After that, you can call `IsPowerUser` as many times as you want. It only talks to the database once for every user.

Comment: thank you so much... This is what i really want. Its working fine. Is this really optimize application performance  when we monitoring memory usage and execution speed . I have only 8 data items like this

Comment: I'm not sure if that was a question or a statement. Anyhow, database operations should be considered "expensive" compared to a simple dictionary lookup. The difference for 8 users is probably negligible, but try serving 8000 users at once without caching.